# Poplulating list of user in a textbox like whatsapp in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to populate list of user when a user press @ button in a textbox like whatsapp "group" in angularjs.
 html is 
`<input class="nostyle search-filter" ng-model="searchUsers" type="text" placeholder="Search" />`

controller' `$scope.allGroupMembers` ' 
is an array which contains all users for the group. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Have you looked into JQuery Auto Complete?

Comment: clarify your question and your allgroupMembers array contains what means is it contains member name or object. Please clear it.

Comment: It contains object in which name is a property which show be shown to user and that name concatenate with the text of input box.

Answer (score 0):

Use $watch to trigger showList when user enters "@"

HTML

```
<input class="nostyle search-filter" ng-model="searchUsers" type="text" placeholder="Search" />

  <div ng-show="showList">
    <div ng-repeat="user in allGroupMembers">
      {{user.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
$scope.showList=false;


$scope.$watch('searchUsers'. function(newValue, oldValue){
   if(newValue[newValue.length]==='@'){

       $scope.showList=true; //Function to show list of user from array.
   }

});
```